# Не отображаются данные в dataGridView

Tags: c#, ado.net

**Используется**
C#
MySql

Не отображаются данные в dataGridView.
Пробовал три варианта запроса. Ни один не работает.

```
string sql_tbl_3 = "SELECT * FROM " + textBox1.Text ; // Строка запроса. НЕ РАБОТАЕТ ХХХ
  // string sql_tbl_3 = "SELECT * FROM tst_011_01_test"; // Строка запроса. НЕ РАБОТАЕТ ХХХ                         
  // string sql_tbl_3 = "SELECT * FROM " + textBox33.Text ; // Строка запроса. НЕ РАБОТАЕТ ХХХ
```

Скрин
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**[Ссылка](http://transfiles.ru/3fvc7) на проект**

Полный код

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

// MySql
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;




namespace dgDvw_3_tbl_01
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        // MySql ПОДКЛЮЧЕНИЕ К БД
        string connStrMySql_db1;
        MySqlConnection connMySql_db1;

        // MySql ТБЛ 3
        MySqlCommand sqlCom_tbl_3;
        MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter_tbl_3;

        DataTable dt_tbl_3_msql;        
        BindingSource bs_mysql_tbl_3;

        #region *** АТОМАТИЧЕСКОЕ ЗАПОЛНЕНИЕ ***
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button11.PerformClick(); // подключение БД

            button25.PerformClick(); // подключение таблицы
            button26.PerformClick(); // создание DataTable
            button27.PerformClick(); // ВЫВОД ДАННЫХ В dataGridView1

        }
        #endregion *** АТОМАТИЧЕСКОЕ ЗАПОЛНЕНИЕ ***. КОНЕЦ ХХХ

        /*
         *** *** *** *****
         *** ПОДКЛ БД ***
         *** *** *** *****
        */
        #region *** ПОДКЛЮЧЕНИЕ БД ***
        private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                /*
                 Пример взят из
                 [url]http://xn--d1aiecikab7a.xn--p1ai/c_sharp_2/[/url]
                 */
                string serverName = textBox9.Text; // Адрес сервера (для локальной базы пишите "localhost")                
                string dbName = textBox10.Text; // Имя базы данных                
                string port = textBox11.Text; // Порт для подключения
                string userName = textBox12.Text; // Имя пользователя
                string password = textBox13.Text; // Пароль для подключения

                connStrMySql_db1 = "server=" + serverName +
                   ";user=" + userName +
                   ";database=" + dbName +
                   ";port=" + port +
                   ";password=" + password + ";";

                connMySql_db1 = new MySqlConnection(connStrMySql_db1);
                connMySql_db1.Open();

                #region *** ИНФО СООБЩЕНИЕ ***
                richTextBox1.Text += (" " + "\r\n");  // инфо сообщение 
                richTextBox1.Text += ("ПОДКЛЮЧИЛИСЬ к БД 1 !!! " + "\r\n");  // инфо сообщение об успешном подключении 
                richTextBox1.Text += ("База данных: " + textBox10.Text + "\r\n");  // инфо сообщение об успешном подключении к БД

                // ПОДСВЕТКА                
                // [url]http://www.hdsw.ru/?p=16[/url]          
                richTextBox1.Select(richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf("ПОДКЛЮЧИЛИСЬ к БД 1 !!!"), "ПОДКЛЮЧИЛИСЬ к БД 1 !!!".Length);
                richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.YellowGreen;

                // ПРОКРУТКА
                richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
                richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
                #endregion *** ИНФО СООБЩЕНИЕ ***. КОНЕЦ ХХХ
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                richTextBox1.AppendText("! " + "\r\n");
                richTextBox1.AppendText("ОШИБКА ХХХ " + "\r\n");

                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show("ОШИБКА ХХХ ");
                return;
            }
        }
        #endregion *** ПОДКЛЮЧЕНИЕ БД ***. КОНЕЦ ХХХ


        /*
         *** *** *** *****
         *** ПОДКЛ ТБЛ ***
         *** *** *** *****
        */
        #region *** ПОДКЛЮЧЕНИЕ ТАБЛИЦ ***
        #region *** ПОДКЛЮЧЕНИЕ. ТАБЛИЦА 3 ***        
        private void button25_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string sql_tbl_3 = "SELECT * FROM " + textBox1.Text ; // Строка запроса. НЕ РАБОТАЕТ ХХХ
                // string sql_tbl_3 = "SELECT * FROM tst_011_01_test"; // Строка запроса. НЕ РАБОТАЕТ ХХХ                         
                // string sql_tbl_3 = "SELECT * FROM " + textBox33.Text ; // Строка запроса. НЕ РАБОТАЕТ ХХХ
                sqlCom_tbl_3 = new MySqlCommand(sql_tbl_3, connMySql_db1);               

                sqlCom_tbl_3.ExecuteNonQuery();

                #region *** ИНФО СООБЩЕНИЕ ***                                
                richTextBox1.Text += " " + "\r\n";
                richTextBox1.Text += ("ТАБЛИЦА " + textBox33.Text + "   ПОДКЛЮЧЕНА !!! " + "\r\n");  // инфо сообщение об успешном подключении к Таблице

                // ПОДСВЕТКА      
                // [url]http://www.hdsw.ru/?p=16[/url]                    
                richTextBox1.Select(richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(" ПОДКЛЮЧЕНА !!! "), " ПОДКЛЮЧЕНА !!! ".Length);
                richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.LimeGreen;

                // ПРОКРУТКА
                richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
                richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
                #endregion *** ИНФО СООЩЕНИЕ ***. КОНЕЦ ХХХ
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                richTextBox1.AppendText("! " + "\r\n");
                richTextBox1.AppendText("ОШИБКА ХХХ " + "\r\n");
                richTextBox1.AppendText(ex + "\r\n");

                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show("ОШИБКА ХХХ ");
                return;
            }
        }
        #endregion *** ПОДКЛЮЧЕНИЕ. ТАБЛИЦА 3  ***. КОНЕЦ ХХХ
        #endregion *** ПОДКЛЮЧЕНИЕ ТАБЛИЦ ***


        /*
       *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
       *** СОЗДАНИЕ DataTable ***
       *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
        */
        #region *** СОЗДАНИЕ DataTable ***            
        #region *** СОЗДАНИЕ DataTable ТАБЛИЦА 3 ***
        private void button26_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                dataAdapter_tbl_3 = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlCom_tbl_3);
                dt_tbl_3_msql = new DataTable();

                dataAdapter_tbl_3.Fill(dt_tbl_3_msql);

                bs_mysql_tbl_3 = new BindingSource();

                bs_mysql_tbl_3.DataSource = dt_tbl_3_msql;

                #region *** ИНФО СООБЩЕНИЕ ***                
                richTextBox1.Text += (" " + "\r\n");  // инфо сообщение 
                richTextBox1.Text += ("СОЗДАН ''DataTable'' ДЛЯ ТБЛ 3 !!! " + "\r\n");  // инфо сообщение об успешном подключении 
                richTextBox1.Text += ("Таблица: ''" + textBox33.Text + "'' " + "\r\n");  // инфо сообщение об успешном подключении к БД
                //richTextBox1.Text += ("Таблица: " + textBox11.Text + "\r\n");  // инфо сообщение об успешном подключении к Таблице

                // ПОДСВЕТКА                
                // [url]http://www.hdsw.ru/?p=16[/url]          
                richTextBox1.Select(richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf("СОЗДАН ''DataTable'' ДЛЯ ТБЛ 3 !!!"), "СОЗДАН ''DataTable'' ДЛЯ ТБЛ 3 !!!".Length);              
                richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.YellowGreen;

                // ПРОКРУТКА
                richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
                richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();                
                #endregion *** ИНФО СООБЩЕНИЕ ***. КОНЕЦ ХХХ            

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                richTextBox1.AppendText("! " + "\r\n");
                richTextBox1.AppendText("  ОШИБКА ХХХ  " + "\r\n");
                richTextBox1.AppendText(ex + "\r\n");

                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show("ОШИБКА ХХХ ");
                // return;

                // ПОДСВЕТКА    
                // [url]http://www.hdsw.ru/?p=16[/url]          
                richTextBox1.Select(richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf("  ОШИБКА ХХХ  "), "  ОШИБКА ХХХ  ".Length);
                richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.OrangeRed;
            }
        }
        #endregion *** СОЗДАНИЕ DataTable ТАБЛИЦА 3 ***. КОНЕЦ ХХХ
        #endregion *** СОЗДАНИЕ DataTable ***. КОНЕЦ ХХХ


        /*
        *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
        *** ВЫВОД ДАННЫХ В dataGridView1 ***
        *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
       */
        #region *** ВЫВОД ДАННЫХ В dataGridView1 ***
        #region *** ТБЛ_3. ВЫВОД ДАННЫХ В dataGridView1 ***
        private void button27_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                dataGridView1.DataSource = bs_mysql_tbl_3; //если на форме есть DataGridView (типа dataGridView1), выводите туда!                                       
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                richTextBox1.AppendText("! " + "\r\n");
                richTextBox1.AppendText("  ОШИБКА ХХХ  " + "\r\n");
                richTextBox1.AppendText(ex + "\r\n");

                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show("ОШИБКА ХХХ ");
                // return;

                // ПОДСВЕТКА    
                // [url]http://www.hdsw.ru/?p=16[/url]          
                richTextBox1.Select(richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf("  ОШИБКА ХХХ  "), "  ОШИБКА ХХХ  ".Length);
                richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.OrangeRed;
            }
        }
        #endregion *** ТБЛ_3. ВЫВОД ДАННЫХ В dataGridView1 ***. КОНЕЦ ХХХ
        #endregion *** ВЫВОД ДАННЫХ В dataGridView1 ***. КОНЕЦ ХХХ


    }
}
```

Comment: А в БД данные есть?

Comment: @Alexander Petrov есть. Причём в некоторых файлах этот код работает после замену ТекстБокса с именем таблицы... Значит проблема в нём.. Только что в нём может быть такое?